# Url Parameter Error in Google Appscript with ContentService, MimeType XML

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting some issue when taking value form parameter here is my simple code in Google App script and deployed service. what is the issue ?

```
function doGet(e) {
  var num = e.parameter.num;
  var result=false;
  result=(num%2==0);
  if(result){
     return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);
    }else{
     return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);
  }

 }
```

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz86LRyPqowhg_ajj48oM13aESMPms30tbne-_p9sWwJVcaQzg/exec?num=20

[Here is google appscript deployed url](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz86LRyPqowhg_ajj48oM13aESMPms30tbne-_p9sWwJVcaQzg/exec?num=20)

This error I am getting when I am hitting this url
[image]

and code running error in App-script Environment
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that the issue might come from the modulo operation you are trying to apply to a string value, when I try this code it runs without error

```
function doGet(e) {
  var num = Number(e.parameter.num);// make it a number before testing parity
  var result=false;
  result=(num%2==0);
  var xmlContent = '<mydata>' + result+ num + '</mydata>';// added num value for test purpose
  if(result){
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(xmlContent).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);
  }else{
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(xmlContent).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);
  } 
}
```

That said, I suppose this is just a test code because I don't really see what it can be used for and the xml output is not valid but I'll leave you with that issue.

[image]

Comment: i am still getting issue after cast to Number then deployed it [link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz86LRyPqowhg_ajj48oM13aESMPms30tbne-_p9sWwJVcaQzg/exec?num=20)

Comment: (https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz86LRyPqowhg_ajj48oM13aESMPms30tbne-_p9sWwJVcaQzg/exec?num=20)                                  this one url is after deployment i am passing num=20

Comment: Thanks @Serge insas for this its working fine. Problem was Casting and with new version deployment in App-script.

Comment: you're welcome, thanks. Modulo was the first issue indeed, the rest is just "technical details" ;-)